# What is the virtual Memory?

Tags: linux, memory

What is virtual memory?
<strike>Hello</strike>

Virtual memory in Linux is quite done?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont understand, can you clarify?

Comment: Is the questions 'what is virtual memory?'

Comment: please complete your question, not ask in bad way :D

Answer (score 2):

Virtual memory is a technique implemented in most every modern operating system, that allow the user to address a virtual quantity of memory that is more than the real physical memory avaible in your machine. 
For example your bynaries are dived into virtual units called segments. For running a program there isn't the necessity of loading every segment of the program into memory, but only the segments that are currently used in computation. So a program typically uses less memory than which it would uses if it was completely loaded into RAM space.
If the sum of all active threads in your operating system overcome the avaible space, typically the operating system Linux uses a swap partition that allow the secondary memory space (your disk) to temporarily store the unused program segments, so that the multitask scheduler can still perform its job.